# how to convert IP address in char[] to Uint32_t in c?

Tags: c

I write a program which takes IP address as an argument and i wanted to store this IP address in the unit32_t. I can easily convert uint32_t to back to character array. How to convert IP address in Char Array to uint32_t.

For example

> ./IPtoCHAR 1079733050

uint32_t to IP Address => 64.91.107.58

But how to write a program that does the reverse task?

> ./CHARtoIP 64.91.107.58

---

for the first IPtoCHAR, it is

> unsigned int ipAddress = atoi(argv[1]);
>
> printf("IP Address %d.%d.%d.%d \n",((ipAddress >> 24) & 0xFF),((ipAddress >> 16) & 0xFF),((ipAddress >> 8) & 0xFF),(ipAddress & 0xFF));

But all these below does not work

> uint32_t aa=(uint32_t)("64.91.107.58");
>
> uint32_t aa=atoi("64.91.107.58");
>
> uint32_t aa=strtol("64.91.107.58",NULL,10);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You use the [`inet_pton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html). function

And for the other way around you should have used [`inet_ntop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html).

---

For Windows-specific documentation, see [`inet_pton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_pton) and [`inet_ntop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop).

---

Note that the functions can be used for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't have access to inet_* functions or need to code this yourself due to any other strange reason, you can use a function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Convert human readable IPv4 address to UINT32
 * @param pDottedQuad   Input C string e.g. "192.168.0.1"
 * @param pIpAddr       Output IP address as UINT32
 * return 1 on success, else 0
 */
int ipStringToNumber (const char*       pDottedQuad,
                              unsigned int *    pIpAddr)
{
   unsigned int            byte3;
   unsigned int            byte2;
   unsigned int            byte1;
   unsigned int            byte0;
   char              dummyString[2];

   /* The dummy string with specifier %1s searches for a non-whitespace char
    * after the last number. If it is found, the result of sscanf will be 5
    * instead of 4, indicating an erroneous format of the ip-address.
    */
   if (sscanf (pDottedQuad, "%u.%u.%u.%u%1s",
                  &byte3, &byte2, &byte1, &byte0, dummyString) == 4)
   {
      if (    (byte3 < 256)
           && (byte2 < 256)
           && (byte1 < 256)
           && (byte0 < 256)
         )
      {
         *pIpAddr  =   (byte3 << 24)
                     + (byte2 << 16)
                     + (byte1 << 8)
                     +  byte0;

         return 1;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```